# If $f'(x)>0$ on $E$ , where $m(E)>0,$ then $m(f(E))>0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,$ and suppose $f$ is differentiable at every point of a measurable $E\subset \mathbb R,$ with $f'>0$ on $E$.
>
> Suppose also that $m(E)>0$ (where $m$ is Lebesgue measure).
>
> Prove that $m(f(E))>0$.

**My proof:**

Since $f$ is differentiable then it's continuous and hence it preserves both compact sets and intervals.

Now since $m(E)>0$ we can find compact interval inside it (is this true or not?)
If this is true so the proof is completed.

I know that if $E$ is measurable then $E$ is either Borel set or a set of measure zero.

So here $E$ is Borel, but still not necessarily to be an interval.

Comment: I guess that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ - is that it ? And is $f$ defined only on $E$ ?

Comment: For the "find a compact set inside", you can provided the measure is what's known as _regular_.  [This theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure) tells you the Lebesgue measure is, though you should make sure you've seen it before.

Comment: @charMD yes on R

Comment: Plus, a measurable set is not either a Borel set or a set of measure zero. A measurable set is the union of a Borel set and a set of measure zero. (See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769084/prove-that-lebesgue-measurable-set-is-the-union-of-a-borel-measurable-set-and-a )

Comment: No, the set of irrational numbers has positive measure but doesn't contain any interval.

Comment: @OpenBall hmmm that is true , so my proof is incorrect

Comment: @charMD thanks for the correction

Comment: You are welcome. I think that you should assume that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (or otherwise you are likely to have problems when defining $f'$)

Comment: @charMD , yes I replied you that f is defined on R

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that, thank you.

Comment: I am trying to prove it as follows :   If not ,i.e m(f(E))=0 Then since E ⊆ f^-1(f(E)) so m(f^-1(f(E))>0 But we assumed m(f(E))=0 So can we say that the measure of preimage of set of measure zero is zero??  If yes then we can get a contradiction

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but $m(f(E^c))\leq \int_{E^c} |f'|$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM $f$ is assumed to be differentiable only on $E$, isn't it ? Plus, $f'$ needs not be Lebesgue-integrable (if we do not suppose so, I mean)

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable everywhere, or just on $E?$

Comment: f is defined on R, and assumed to be differentiable only on E ,with f'(x)>0 on E

Comment: It's not even clear that $f(E)$ is measurable from the given hypotheses.

Comment: I want to ask the OP: Is this really the problem? is this the exact wording?where does it come from?

Comment: it is an exam question

Comment: can we say that E contains open interval since f is diffrentiable on E , and diffrentiablity defined on interior points?

Comment: @charMD  can you put your solution ,thanks in advance

Comment: @user283366 No, it is possible for $f$ to be differentiable at every point of a closed set with empty interior (a Cantor set for instance), and discontinuous outside it. Thus $f'$ can very well be defined only at a set with empty interior. To create such a function, use something like that http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602163/example-of-a-function-differentiable-in-a-point-but-not-continuous-in-a-neighbo/1752990#1752990 . Tell me if you want more details

Comment: @user283366 OK it's an exam question. But have you given us the exact wording?

Comment: @zhw. Yes I am almost sure,It's a final exam question , I will ask my prof at the beginning of next semester

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will prove two points : first, in response to a comment of zhw, we check that $f(E)$ is measurable, and then that its measure is $>0$.

We recall that $m^*$ denotes here Lebesgue outer measure, defined for every subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. For $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, we note $l(I) = \sup I - \inf I$. Then we define $$m^*(S) = \inf \left \{ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} l(I_k),\ (I_k)_{k \ge 1} \textrm{ is a sequence of intervals with } S \subset \bigcup \limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*} I_k \right \}$$

For both results, the following lemma will be needed.

> **Lemma :** Given $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at any point of a set $S$, assuming that there exists $C \ge 0$ such that $\forall x \in S,\ |f'(x)| \le C$, then $m^* \big( f(S) \big) \le C \cdot m^*(S)$.

*Proof : Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We define an increasing sequence of sets $(S_n)_{n \ge 1}$ by : $$S_n = \left \{ x \in S,\ \forall t \in S,\ |t-x| \le \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow |f(t)-f(x)| \le (C+\varepsilon)|t-x| \right \}$$*

*Using the hypothesis $|f'|\le C$, we get that $S = \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$. For every $n \ge 1$, we can take a sequence of open intervals $(I_{n,k})_{k \ge 1}$ covering $S_n$ and such that 
$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} m^*(I_{n,k}) \le m^*(S_n)+\varepsilon.$*

*Without loss of generality, we can assume that for every $n$ and $k$, $m^*(I_{n,k}) \le \frac{1}{n}$.*

*Then, for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, for $x,y \in S_n \cap I_{n,k}$, we have $|y-x|\le \frac{1}{n}$ and $x,y \in S_n$, so we can write $|f(y)-f(x)| \le (C+\varepsilon)|y-x|\le (C+\varepsilon)\cdot m^*(I_{n,k})$.
Thus, for $n \ge 1$, $$m^*(f(S_n)) \le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} m^*\big(f(S_n \cap I_{n,k}) \big) \le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} (C+\varepsilon)\cdot m^*(I_{n,k}) \le (C+\varepsilon)\cdot (m^*(S_n)+\varepsilon)$$*

*Letting $n \to +\infty$ and then $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, we get $m^* \big( f(S) \big) \le C \cdot m^* (S)$.*

---

Now we prove that $f(E)$ is measurable. Classically (see [Problem about $G_{\delta}$ and $F_{\delta}$ sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737699/problem-about-g-delta-set-and-f-sigma-set)),

> **Claim 1 :** There exists a subset $H \subset E$ which is $F_{\delta}$ (i.e. a countable union of closed sets) such that $N=E \backslash H$ is a null set.

Write $H = \bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} F_k$ where the $F_k$ are closed. For $k \ge 1$, for all $M>0$, $[-M,M] \cap F_k$ is compact and $f$ is continuous (because it is differentiable) on this set, so $f([-M,M]\cap F_k)$ is closed (it is a compact set).
So for all $k$, $f(F_k) = \bigcup \limits_{M \in \mathbb{N}^*} f\big([-M,M]\cap F_k\big)$ is a Borel set, so $f(H)$ is measurable.

Now we prove that $f(N)$ is a null set. For $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we denote $N_k = \{ x \in N,\ f'(x)<k \}$. $N_k \subset N$ so $N_k$ is a null set, so $m^*(N_k)=0$ for $k \ge 1$. Plus, we can use the previous lemma on $N_k$, because $0 \le f' \le k$ on $N_k$, so $m^* \big(f(N_k) \big)\le 0$.
Thus $f(N_k)$ is a null set. As $f(E) = f(H) \cup f(N)$, we can conclude that $$f(E) \textrm{ is measurable}.$$

---

Now back to the original problem : we have some measurable set $E$ with positive measure, $f$ differentiable on $E$, $f'>0$ on E. We suppose that $m \big( f(E) \big)=0$.

For $x \in E$, $f'(x)>0$ so $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}>0$ for all $y \in E \backslash \{x \}$ in some neighborhood of $x$. Thus 
\begin{align*}
E & = \bigcup \limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \left \{ x \in E\ | \ \ x > q \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall y \in ]q,x[,\ \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}>0 \right \}\\ 
& = \bigcup \limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \left \{ x \in E\ | \ \ x > q \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall y \in ]q,x[,\ f(x)>f(y) \right \}
\end{align*}

because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense. Moreover, $E$ has positive measure and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Hence, there exists $q_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $B = \left \{ x \in E\ | \ \ x > q_0 \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall y \in ]q_0,x[,\ f(x)>f(y) \right \}$ has positive measure.

Plus, for $(x,y) \in B^2$ with $x<y$, we have $q_0 < x <y$, so $f(y)>f(x)$. Hence $f_{|B}$ is increasing.

Finally it is a well-known fact (see [Can we have an uncountable number of isolated points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443010/can-we-have-an-uncountable-number-of-isolated-points)) that $B$ has countably many isolated points, and thus we have a measurable subset $A \subset B$ such that $m(A)=m(B)>0$ and $A$ has no isolated points. Note that we also have $f_{|A}$ increasing, $f'>0$ on A, and $m \big( f(A) \big)=0$.

Now we just need a stronger version of our lemma :

> **Lemma (bis) :** Given $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with no isolated points, and $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in A$ whenever $\lim \limits_{t \to x^{\neq}} \frac{f(x)-f(t)}{x-t}$ exists, and we note $f'(x)$ the limit. Assuming that $f$ is differentiable over $A$, and that there exists $C \ge 0$ such that $|f'| \le C$, we have $$m^* \big( f(A) \big) \le C \cdot m^*(A)$$

*Proof : the proof is exactly the same as the one we gave for the first lemma.*

Finally, we denote $g = f_{|A}$. As $g$ is stricly increasing, $g^{-1}$ is well defined. Moreover, as $f'>0$ on $A$, it is classical (see [Inverse functions and differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)) to show that $g^{-1}$ is differentiable *in the sense of the Lemma bis* on $g(A)$. As $g(A)$ is a null set, we can use our lemma (as we did with the set $N$ - see above) to conclude that $g^{-1}\big( g(A) \big)$ is a null set, so $A$ is a null set, which is absurd.

$$\textrm{Hence we have }\ m \big (f(E) \big) > 0.$$

Comment: Thank you CharMD for your valuable answer .I follow up with your answer until the last step where you said that f^-1 is differentiable (where the result follow immediately as you proved above) so how can we guarantee differentiability of f^-1  ?

Comment: Also you mean at the end the set A is it self the set E :)?

Comment: If $f$ is stricly monotone and that $f'(x)$ exists, with $0<f'(x)<+\infty$, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $f(x)$ with derivative $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$. This can be found in various course of calculus (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)

Comment: In the end, I managed to use only classic tools, but still, this is not an easy question for an exam

Comment: @charMD It is not necessarily the case that $f|_A$ is increasing. Think of $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$. However, as can be inferred following the proof in the link to the Bogachev book, there exists a subset of $A$ with positive measure on which $f$ is increasing, and from here you can apply the rest of the proof.

Comment: @Del : indeed, you are right. What is currently wrong in my proof is when I approach $t_0$ below, which can sometimes be impossible. I will modify my proof accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can prove this by using the following result, which you can find in V. I. Bogachev's Measure Theory book (Springer, 2007). This is Lemma 5.8.13., which I quote almost verbatim but with adapted notation:

> **Proposition**: Let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$ and let $A$ be the set of all points at which $f$ has a nonzero derivative. Then, for every set $Z$ of measure zero, the set $f^{-1}(Z) \cap A$ has measure zero. In other words, $\lambda \circ f^{-1}|_A \ll \lambda|_A$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

Here is a [link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=bogachev+measure+theory+nonzero+derivative&source=bl&ots=lSMvjtIakc&sig=qSAYHY1a3PkTCdihMGVZDM0SFCw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg8Jq0nbvRAhVDw4MKHfnAD6gQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=bogachev%20measure%20theory%20nonzero%20derivative&f=false) to the proof given by Bogachev. It is quite unwieldy (to me, at least) and I must say I haven't gone through the details. The proof relies on Vitali's covering theorem.

Note that the proposition remains true for a function $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$: just write $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable almost-disjoint union of intervals and apply the proposition to the restriction of $f$ to each interval.

To solve the problem at hand, we argue by contradiction and suppose that $m(f(E)) =0$. Since $E \subset f^{-1}(f(E))$ and $E \subset A$, we have $E \subset f^{-1}(f(E)) \cap A$. Since $f(E)$ has measure $0$, the proposition implies that $f^{-1}(f(E)) \cap A$ has measure $0$. This is a contradiction since we assumed that $m(E) >0$.

**Remark**: In the above we assumed that $f(E)$ is measurable. This does follow from the hypotheses. See CharMD's [great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093961/258909) for a proof, or alternatively [Proposition 5.5.4.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CoSIe7h5mTsC&pg=PA348&lpg=PA348&dq=bogachev+measure+theory+extra+summand&source=bl&ots=lSMvjtH9kd&sig=UHK7dre4bIM5DYRImWYyhM_iqWk&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMkfmnmbvRAhVk0oMKHTARCDoQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=bogachev%20measure%20theory%20extra%20summand&f=false) in Bogachev's book.

Comment: Have you read Bogachev in its entirety ? :D

Comment: I haven't; just some sections here and there. I mostly use it as a reference and for the abundant exercises (about a hundred per chapter!). Why do you ask?

Answer (score -4):

From $f'>0$, there exists $c>0$ such that $f'>c$. Then $$m(f(E))=\int_{E} f' dm>\int_{E} c dm=c\int_{E} 1 dm=cm(E)>0.$$

Comment: How does m(f(E))=∫f'. ?can you give me a reference?

Comment: @user283366 $m(f(E))=\int_{y\in f(E)}1\ dy.$Substitute $y=f(x).$Then, 
$
m(f(E))=\int_{x\in E}f'(x)\ dx$

Comment: Isn't the monotonicity of $f$ usually required for such a substitution ?